# What is the vertical property on NSStatusBar?

Tags: cocoa, nsstatusbar

I just looked at the Apple documentation for `NSStatusBar`, and found this curious property:

> `vertical` *Property*
>
> A Boolean value indicating whether the status bar has a vertical orientation. >(read-only)
>
> #### Declaration
>
> ```
> @property(getter=isVertical, readonly) BOOL vertical
> ```
>
> #### Discussion
>
> When the value of this property is `YES`, the status bar has a vertical orientation. The status bar returned by the `systemStatusBar` method is horizontal and has the value `NO` for this property.
>
> #### Availability
>
> Available in OS X v10.10 and later.

It's unclear whether this is used anywhere, because it's apparently  not really used on `[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]`, which as far as I know is the only instance.

What is this for?

Comment: That's very interesting, but I don't have any insight for you.